# How to stop pandas merge() function to do cartesian product when key values are repeated?

Tags: python, cartesian-product

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2], "b": [1,1]})
b = pd.DataFrame({"c": [3,4], "b": [1,1]})
c = a.merge(b, on=['b'], how='inner')
```

we will get c having 4 lines. But how can we get c like {'a':[1,2], 'c':[3,4], 'b':[1,1]} by using merge() function?

Answer (score 1):

This could work. Pandas merge is not that good when you implement it.

```
c = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1, join='inner')
c = c.loc[:,~c.columns.duplicated()]
print(c)
```

returns this:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  3
1  2  1  4
```

Comment: a useful answer which i will use in the future, so i added the return value for clarity.